# Get IP address of other RPi connected directly with LAN

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, ip-address, lan

I have two RPis connected together directly with a LAN cable, I would like to know how can I get, with Python, the IP address (eth0) of the RPi from the other one?

I know how to get the IP address of the RPi itself. But for the other one, I don't know, I found a solution by scanning the whole network. But I guess it should have a simpler way, as I connect the 2 devices directly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
ip neighbour
```

to list the ips connected.

Comment: I cannot see the IP address of the other RPi with the command :(

Comment: Hmm... and what does it show? It should extract the ARP cache entries, and get the neighbours information from there. You can also try the arp command from net-tools for the same thing. If the two nodes can communicate via IP ove ethernet, then there should be a valid ARP entry.

Comment: I restarted the RPi and now it works, I see the IPs on the list. I have to find a way to extract in Python now :)

Comment: ARP have a timeout, it will disappear after few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan your whole LAN and filter with "Raspberry Pi Foundation" owned mac-address.

Example:

```
$ sudo nmap -p 22 192.168.1.0/24 --open

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-04-16 10:55 CEST
Nmap scan report for _gateway (192.168.1.1)
Host is up (0.00048s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
MAC Address: 0A:E5:4C:69:45:1E (Unknown)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.5
Host is up (0.0013s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
MAC Address: 64:00:F1:4D:32:D1 (Cisco Systems)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.12
Host is up (0.00037s latency).

PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
MAC Address: B8:27:EB:F3:FD:7F (Raspberry Pi Foundation)

Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (9 hosts up) scanned in 8.56 seconds
```

If ssh is opened on them, you can filter on this port, if not you can use a simple ping with "-sP" instead of "-p 22".

If nmap does not show you mac-prefix owner you can also filter with known prefixes for them (`B8:27:EB:`, `DC:A6:32:`, `E4:5F:01:`).

In my sample, my rPI is at 192.168.1.12!